# How to alias imports in meteor? (react-native-web)

Tags: meteor, react-native-web

I am trying to use [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/master/docs/guides/getting-started.md#webpack-and-babel) in my Meteor client-side application. React-native web requires that you alias the `react-native` import declaration to `react-native-web`, this way the components you write on the React Native side will map directly to web components without having to do ANY additional customizations.

I.e.

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
```

in your code should get resolved to

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-web';
```

when executed in the Meteor app, while resolving to the default `react-native` module when executed in the React Native app.

How do you achieve this sort of module aliasing in Meteor?